# SQL query to get status as of a given date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm sure this has been answered before but couldn't find it.

I have a table of items which change status every few weeks.  I want to look at an arbitrary day and figure out how many items were in each status.

For example:

**tbl_ItemHistory**

```
ItemID
StatusChangeDate
StatusID
```

Sample data:

```
1001, 1/1/2010, 1
1001, 4/5/2010, 2
1001, 6/15/2010, 4
1002, 4/1/2010, 1
1002, 6/1/2010, 3
...
```

So I need to figure out how many items were in each status for a given day.  So on 5/1/2010, there was one item (1001) in status 2 and one item in status 1 (1002).

Since these items don't change status very often, maybe I could create a cached table every night that has a row for every item and every day of the year?  I'm not sure if that's best or how to do that though

I'm using SQL Server 2008R2

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)? What query did you try that did not work? What exactly about this are you stuck with?

Comment: My first question is the approach:  will I need to cache the results to another table?  If so, how do I do that?  I'm a newbie to SQL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For an arbitrary day, you can do something like this:

```
select ih.*
from (select ih.*,
             row_number() over (partition by itemId order by StatusChangeDate desc) as seqnum
      from tbl_ItemHistory ih
      where StatusChangeDate <= @YOURDATEGOESHERE
     ) ih
where seqnum = 1
```

The idea is to enumerate all the history records for each on or before the date,using `row_nubmer`.  The ordering is in reverse chronological order, so the most recent record -- on or before the date -- has a value of 1.

The query then just chooses the records whose value is 1.

To aggregate the results to get each status for the date, use:

```
select statusId, count(*)
from (select ih.*,
             row_number() over (partition by itemId order by StatusChangeDate desc) as seqnum
      from tbl_ItemHistory ih
      where StatusChangeDate <= @YOURDATEGOESHERE
     ) ih
where seqnum = 1
group by StatusId
```

Comment: You're right Gordon, I missed that part of the question. I'll withdraw my answer to avoid confusion...

Comment: That's great.   I'll have to go study the partition function.  Let's say I did want to create a table that has a row for every item and every day of the year.  That would allow me to do some reporting easier.  How would I do that?

Comment: @user46372 . . . You have an opportunity to ask another question.

Comment: Sounds good.  I put it here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13726432/newbie-cache-event-change-table-with-every-date